# Number of days between two dates return wrong value

Tags: php, date

This may be the silly error.But still i got this only in my application.i could not identify the issue. When i tried the same in PHPFiddle ,it works fine. My PHPFIddle code is below:

```
<?php
    $FirstDate = '2018-03-25';
    $LastDate = '2018-03-31';

    $endDate =  strtotime($LastDate);
    $startDate = strtotime($FirstDate);         

    $days = floor(($endDate - $startDate) / 86400 + 1);

    $no_full_weeks = floor($days / 7);
    $no_remaining_days = fmod($days, 7);

    echo $days;
    echo $no_full_weeks ;
    echo $no_remaining_days;

?>
```

The output is  `7  1  0.`

But i do the same in my application, but it shows output as

```
 private function getWorkingDays($FirstDate,$LastDate,$holidays){

        // i hard coded here for checking only these two dates  
        $FirstDate = '2018-03-25';
        $LastDate = '2018-03-31';           
        $endDate =  strtotime($LastDate);
        $startDate = strtotime($FirstDate);         

        error_log("from".$FirstDate);   
        error_log("to".$LastDate);                  

        $days = floor(($endDate - $startDate) / 86400 + 1);
        error_log("days". $days );
        $no_full_weeks = floor($days / 7);
        $no_remaining_days = fmod($days, 7);

        error_log("no_full_weeks". $no_full_weeks );    
        error_log("no_remaining_days".$no_remaining_days);    
       return $days;    
}
```

THe output is

```
 from 2018-03-25

 to 2018-03-31

 days 6

 no_full_weeks 0

 no_remaining_days 6
```

The problem comes for only these two dates. For 18th to 24th march. it works fine.

Comment: Did the clocks change from winter to summer time somewhere between those dates

Comment: Don't use `strotiime()` for date math. It wasn't made for such things. Use `DateTime()` and its related classes which account for things such as Daylight Savings time and timezones.

Comment: I must look that function up @JohnConde :) :) :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've heard good things about it. ;)

Comment: https://eval.in/980650

Answer (score -1):

to add to @JohnConde comment. you can use this and work with timestamps. its much easier to work with

```
 $date = new DateTime(); 
 print $date->getTimestamp(); //prints something like 1522252715
```

for it to return the current day/month/year time etc.

you can use [`date();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to handle any format you would like it to output such as `2018-03-25`

```
print date("y-m-d",$date->getTimestamp()); //prints out 2018-03-29
```

Comment: @JohnConde the `DateTime();` function can be quite useful :)

Comment: Why would you use `date()` when you have `DateTime` object?

Comment: to convert the unix timestamp `1522252715` to this `2018-03-29`

Comment: And for that you need `date()` function? What about `$date->format('Y-m-d');` ? And `y`=18 format is not same as `Y`=2018...

Comment: Thanks Buddy @Glavić ,  you just thought me something new :) <3. Down vote though :(

Comment: If we ignore wrong-`date()`-schooling, your answer has nothing to do with the question...

Comment: although it provides an output like this `2018-Mar-Thu` ?

Comment: Question title is `Number of days between two dates return wrong value`. What does formatting a date has to do with it?